# UIView added programmatically to UITabBarController displays just black

Tags: ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I am programmatically changing the tab bar item for my tab bar at runtime.
The whole UI of my app uses Storyboards and this is the only area where I am making the UI changes in code.

So, the UI changes depending on a property. If this property cannot be found, the array of viewControllers changes to the new array that contains the new UIView.

Here's my code for the TabBarController.m:

```
NSArray *arrayOfControllers = self.viewControllers;
NSMutableArray *newArrayOfControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (id controller in arrayOfControllers)
{
    [newArrayOfControllers addObject:controller];
}


if ( !isMember)
{
    NotMemberVC *vc = [[NotMemberVC alloc]init];
    vc.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"door-sign.png"] tag:0];

    [newArrayOfControllers removeLastObject];
    [newArrayOfControllers addObject:vc];

    self.viewControllers = newArrayOfControllers;
}
```

And here's what it looks like when I select this new tab bar item:
[image]

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this?

Comment: Where do you create the view for NotMemberVC?

Comment: The view has been created in my single Storyboard

Comment: Then you need to create the controller with the UIStoryboard method, instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:, not alloc init.

Comment: Umm, I don't know how to do that.
Do you have any sample code or link that shows me how to do this?
This is my first view that I create completely in code so I'm a bit lost

Comment: Oh, do you mean instead of this:
        NotMemberVC *vc = [[NotMemberVC alloc]init];?

Comment: Look at Matteo's answer.

Comment: Ahh, I just saw it. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need to do a for cycle when you have a method to do a `mutableCopy` of the array:

```
NSArray *arrayOfControllers = self.viewControllers;
NSMutableArray *newArrayOfControllers = [arrayOfControllers mutableCopy];
```

then here, **you was not initializating the viewController with the view**. In this case **you have your VC with the UIView in your storyboard**, and so **you have to choose a StoryboardID in your VC in the Storyboard**, and then:

```
if ( !isMember)
{
    NotMemberVC *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Your_Identifier_ViewController_Storyboard"];

    vc.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"door-sign.png"] tag:0];

    [newArrayOfControllers removeLastObject];
    [newArrayOfControllers addObject:vc];

    //Here make a copy to come back to immutable array
    self.viewControllers = [newArrayOfControllers copy];
}
```

Comment: Thank you Matteo, you deserve a beer!

Comment: You are welcome, but don't forget to set this as correct answer that is the most important thing for this community.

Comment: I did...I just had wait 3 mins for some odd reason.

Comment: np ;) enjoy your app!